# terraform_remote_state data block syntax

Tags: terraform, devops, infrastructure-as-code, terraform0.12+

I'm working on an AWS multi-account setup with Terraform. I've got a master account that creates several sub-accounts, and in the sub-accounts I'm referencing the master's remote state to retrieve output values.

The `terraform plan` command is failing for this configuration in a test main.tf:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.12.0"

  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "bucketname"
    key    = "statekey.tfstate"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region  = "us-east-1"
  version = "~> 2.7"
}

data "aws_region" "current" {}

data "terraform_remote_state" "common" {
  backend = "s3"
  config {
        bucket = "anotherbucket"
        key    = "master.tfstate"
  }
}
```

With the following error:

```
➜  test terraform plan

Error: Unsupported block type

  on main.tf line 20, in data "terraform_remote_state" "common":
  20:   config {

Blocks of type "config" are not expected here. Did you mean to define argument
"config"? If so, use the equals sign to assign it a value.
```

From what I can tell from [the documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html), this should be working… what am I doing wrong?

```
➜  test terraform -v  
Terraform v0.12.2
+ provider.aws v2.14.0
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what things are you pulling from remote state? In 99% of cases where people are using the remote state data source I would recommend replacing it with a more native provider data source instead.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I'm pulling out AWS account numbers. The parent account is creating several sub accounts with AWS Organizations for environments and projects, and each project has it's own Terraform config.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems the [related document](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html) isn't updated after upgrade to 0.12.x

As the error prompt, add `=` after `config`

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "common" {
  backend = "s3"
  config = {
        bucket = "anotherbucket"
        key    = "master.tfstate"
  }
}
```

If the problem is fixed, recommend to raise a PR to update the document, then others can avoid the same issue again.

Comment: Sometimes the answer is just staring me right in the face. ‍♂️ This did the trick.